# Android browsers don't initiate a connection for a specific url

Tags: android, http, proxy, timeout, kindle-fire

I'm trying to access http://feeds.boston.com/boston/bigpicture/index from Kindle Fire from both the standard browser and the Dolphin browser.

I'm using Fiddler as a proxy and when I'm requesting http://www.boston.com/bigpicture/index.xml from the Kindle Fire from within the browsers I see the request in Fiddler, it redirects to http://feeds.boston.com/boston/bigpicture/index and the browsers time out without any sign of the request in Fiddler.

I've also tried to navigate to the url directly without the redirect with the same result.

The www.boston.com web site works fine and I see the requests in Fiddler as well as other sites and applications calling home.

The request also times out without the proxy with a direct connection (that's why I tried to debug with the proxy).

The URL works fine from desktop.

Is this some known behavior of Android / Kindle Fire? Is there a rule or a blacklist why it won't make the request and time out?

Answer (score 1):

This was a strange DNS issue.
I've added the feeds.boston.com address to the hosts file of the Kindle Fire and it works.